# How to navigate from one controller to another controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am trying to learn mvc. suppose i have two links in my index page. i want that when i will click on first link then i want MyPageOneController should invoke and MyPageOne view should display.

the same way i want that when i will click on second link then i want MyPageTwoController should invoke and MyPagetwo view should display.

i try to do it but getting error. here i am giving the pic of my controller & view folder structure. just have a look.

[image]

i have one view called MyPageOne which is in home folder and another view in different folder called test.

### here i am giving my full code

**Index.cshtml code**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Click on link one", "MyPageOne", "MyPageOne")&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    @Html.ActionLink("Click on link two", "MyPageTwo", "MyPageTwo")
</p>
```

**MyPageOne.cshtml code**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyPageOne";
}

<h2>Welcome to MyPageOne !</h2>
```

**MyPageTwo.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyPageTwo.cshtml";
}

<h2>Welcome to MyPageTwo !</h2>
```

i have created two controllder called MyPageOneController.cs & MyPageTwoController.cs

**code in MyPageOneController.cs**

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class MyPageOneController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /MyPageOne/

        public ActionResult MyPageOne()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**code in MyPageTwoController.cs**

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
    public class MyPageTwoController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /MyPageTwo/

        public ActionResult MyPageTwo()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

so just guide me what is wrong. i check that when i click on first link then right controller method is getting called but no view is not getting render. where i am making mistake. please guide me what i need to change in my code to load two view created by me and stored in two different folder. thanks

### I got the solution

```
public ActionResult MyPageOne()
        {
            return View("../Home/MyPageOne");
        }

 public ActionResult MyPageTwo()
        {
            //return View();
            return View("../Test/MyPageTwo");
        }
```

this way i redirect to the view and job done.
can u plzz tell me how could i specify programmatically something under view folder.
i use the code  `return View("~/Home/MyPageOne");` but it did not work. how to mention root view folder path??

thanks

Comment: check the folder names, they should be the same as the controller's, as far as I know (Views/MyPageOne/MyPageOne.cshtml for example). Or just right click on the controller's action -> go to view

Comment: Your solution is not the real solution, it is a workaround for having an incorrectly structured view folder.  MVC is a convention based framework, and the controller shouldn't really need any knowledge of the folder structure on disk. The actual solution is one of the answers below.  And to learn more there is a ton of guidance on www.asp.net.  These are the basics so it shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: use return RedirectToAction("action_name", "controller_name");

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your views are in the wrong location.  Try relocating your views into the following view folders:

```
Views -> MyPageOne -> MyPageOne.cshtml
Views -> MyPageTwo -> MyPageTwo.cshtml
```

Comment: i am beginner in mvc so may be ur right but think when i need to create many views in same folder then how could i proceed? every time i need to create a folder having the view name?

Comment: Re your first comment. The view folder is named after the controller and not the view. Take a look at the HomeController example, assuming it's not been edited.  The view folder is called Home, ie the controller class name prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You have the views in wrong folder, "Test" should be "MyPageOne", or you need to write custom routes

Comment: can u plzz guide me how to write custom routes and when to use custom routes. thanks

Comment: can we create subfolder in Controllers folder and write controller in that sub forlder. please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

(I just stared with ASP.NET MVC 5. But I think I can answer this question. ;))

I suggest you take a look at the *ASP.NET MVC conventions*. You placed the .chtml files at the wrong view folder. Conventionally, the **default view** for an action should be placed like this: **Views\< Controller Name >\< Action Name >.chtml**.